# Spring 5.3.9 - upgrade - localization issue - Changing the language not working

Tags: spring-mvc, localization

We have a website running with old Spring MVC framework and have upgraded to 5.3.9. The website allows user to click on English or Spanish languages on the page. After the upgrade, it always stays on English not showing the Spanish.

```
<beans:bean id="publicUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

    <beans:property name="interceptors">
        <beans:list>                
            <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="urlMap">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="/public/login">
                <beans:ref bean="wsLoginController"/>
            </beans:entry>              
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
     <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" /> 
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale" />
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>registryMessages</beans:value>             
        </beans:list>      
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Above configuration did not work so I have added below code in the controller.

URL : search.html?locale=es_MX

```
String language = request.getParameter("locale");       
    if(language == null) {
        language= "en";
    }       
    Locale lc = new Locale(language);       
    RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response,  lc);
```

This is working when I am running localhost(WebSphere application server) . However, when deployed to DEV WebSphere server, problem persists. Tried uninstalling, removing the cache, redeploying etc, but still no luck. Appreciate any help fixing the above code. Is there anyway to make the above configuration without adding the code in controller ? or after adding the small code in the controller, it is working on my localhost, but why is it not working on DEV server ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

URL parameter is locale=es_MX. I have properties files as registryMessages_es_MX.properties. When setting the parameter value to the `Locale lc = new Locale(language);` , it is converting it to lower case. When running on localhost(Windows) it is able to find the properties with uppercase extension but when deployed to DEV(Unix server), it is looking for "_es_mx.proeprties" and failed to load. I have changed all the properties to lowercase extensions "es_mx", worked on both windows and Unix platforms.